# Suddenly a massive amount of binlog files

Tags: mysql, percona, binlog, xtradb-cluster

I've seen a sudden increase of binlog files, very large in number and size, in all three nodes of a Percona XtraDB cluster:

```
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql 1,1G 19 oct.  16:11 binlog-32.000001
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql 1,1G 19 oct.  16:36 binlog-32.000002
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql 1,1G 19 oct.  16:48 binlog-32.000003
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql 1,1G 19 oct.  16:59 binlog-32.000004
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql 1,1G 19 oct.  17:08 binlog-32.000005
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql 1,1G 19 oct.  17:26 binlog-32.000006
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql 1,1G 19 oct.  17:38 binlog-32.000007
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql 1,1G 19 oct.  17:47 binlog-32.000008
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql 1,1G 19 oct.  17:59 binlog-32.000009
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql 1,1G 19 oct.  18:10 binlog-32.000010
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql 1,1G 19 oct.  18:20 binlog-32.000011
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql 1,1G 19 oct.  18:29 binlog-32.000012
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql 1,1G 19 oct.  18:37 binlog-32.000013
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql 1,1G 19 oct.  18:45 binlog-32.000014
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql 1,1G 19 oct.  18:53 binlog-32.000015
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql 1,1G 19 oct.  19:01 binlog-32.000016
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql 1,1G 19 oct.  19:11 binlog-32.000017
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql 1,1G 19 oct.  19:19 binlog-32.000018
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql 1,1G 19 oct.  19:28 binlog-32.000019
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql 1,1G 19 oct.  19:38 binlog-32.000020
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql 1,1G 19 oct.  19:44 binlog-32.000021
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql 1,1G 19 oct.  19:52 binlog-32.000022
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql 1,1G 19 oct.  19:59 binlog-32.000023
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql 1,1G 19 oct.  20:08 binlog-32.000024
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql 1,1G 19 oct.  20:17 binlog-32.000025
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql 1,1G 19 oct.  20:24 binlog-32.000026
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql 1,1G 19 oct.  20:32 binlog-32.000027
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql 1,1G 19 oct.  20:40 binlog-32.000028
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql 1,1G 19 oct.  20:47 binlog-32.000029
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql 1,1G 19 oct.  20:56 binlog-32.000030
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql 1,1G 19 oct.  21:05 binlog-32.000031
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql 1,1G 19 oct.  21:15 binlog-32.000032
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql 1,1G 19 oct.  21:25 binlog-32.000033
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql 1,1G 19 oct.  21:36 binlog-32.000034
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql 1,1G 19 oct.  21:46 binlog-32.000035
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql 1,1G 19 oct.  21:48 binlog-32.000036
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql 254M 20 oct.  09:34 binlog-32.000037
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql  143 20 oct.  09:34 binlog-32.000038
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql  143 20 oct.  09:34 binlog-32.000039
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql  143 20 oct.  09:34 binlog-32.000040
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql  120 20 oct.  09:34 binlog-32.000041
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql 1,2K 20 oct.  09:34 binlog-32.index
```

It appears that an user lanced a script that does quite a lot of SELECTs and UPDATEs over many connections. However, it surprises me how he managed to DoS the server. Is this a reasonable cause, or might be something else, perhaps some misconfiguration?

Comment: Binlog keeps track of all changes made to the database. Every INSERT / UPDATE / DELETE is logged. Massive modifications lead to massive binlog.

Comment: @Kondybas This is an old question, but if you write it as an answer I'll be happy to accept it.

Comment: It's a crime this question isn't titled ["Suddenly, binlog: thousands of them"](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/suddenly-bananas-thousands-of-them)

Answer (score 1):

Your user seems to have cause quite a high workload.

`SELECT`s are not written in the binlog, but `UPDATE`s are (as well as all other data changes).

Settings that affect the binary log size are:

- [`binlog_format`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#sysvar_binlog_format): I recommend to set it to `ROW` for performance reasons, but this may cause your files to take a log of space if `UPDATE`s and `DELETE`s affect many rows.
- [`binlog_row_image`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#sysvar_binlog_row_image): When events are logged in ROW format, this variable is relevant for `UPDATE`, as well as `DELETE` and`REPLACE`: it determines whether the old values are written to the binlog (normally unnecessary, but it can be required by some tools that read the binlog).
- [`binlog_row_metadata`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#sysvar_binlog_row_metadata): Whether columns and primary key metadata are logged.
- [`binlog_row_value_options`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#sysvar_binlog_row_value_options): Whether modifying a part of a JSON document will cause the all document to be written in the binlog.
- [Binary log transaction compression](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/binary-log-transaction-compression.html)

Answer (score -1):

Check `server-id` on in `my.cnf` on each server in your replication topology.  Probably there is a duplicate.  Server ids *must* be different.

Comment: Aren't `server-id` values required to be different only for master-slave replication, and not for Percona XtraDB clusters? The install script of ClusterControl (a tool for managing Percona clusters) does not explicitly specify different values of `server-id` for each PXC node, and here it even recommends the opposite: https://www.percona.com/blog/2015/07/16/bypassing-sst-pxc-binary-logs/

Comment: I stand corrected.  My answer probably does not apply to Galera-based clusters (PXC, MariaDB).